# Is there a way that this is possible? I am trying to find a value of a var constructed by other variables

Tags: javascript, html, var, assign

This is a little bit of my code. I took out the complex parts. It is all on the script tag.

var trueenemyscoutx = '_2'

var tryeenemyscouty = '2'

var type_22 = "none"

var move1;

enemymove = "type" + trueenemyscoutx + trueenemyscouty;

var move1 = (enemymove.valueOf()).valueOf()

Comment: Are you asking to get trueenemyscoutx and truenemyscouty from enemymove? That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the post, `enemymove` is a string constructed by concatenating "type" and two other variables, each of which is also a string.

The resultant string contains no information about the variables used and so the general answer to the question is no, it is not possible using the approach taken.

Obvious alternatives include:

1. Keep `move` a string, but use a separator (e.g. colon, comma or space) between component substrings. This allows extracting an array of the components using [`move.split(separator)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
2. Use an array or simple object to hold move information instead of a string in the first place.